# caused by: java.lang.runtimeException in android studio

Tags: java, runtimeexception

[image]

i have been trying to run a app from android studio but is always showing java lang Runtime Exception error after Gradle build configuration

please help me

Comment: Scroll to the bottom and look at the last "Caused by", since that is the real error.

Comment: in my case its not even showing the stack trace. just
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException

This started after I updated my Android Studio to 3.2.1
I even tried uninstalling and reinstalling the latest Android Studio but the problem persists.